# Silverlight - Save data on mouseout from usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I have silverlight screen, which includes multiple user controls in single screen and in one of screen, I am saving data when user enters anything in textbox on that usercontrol's mouse focus out event.

But sometime, If user click on that checkbox and keeps mouse cursor out from that user control, then event will not get fired as focus is already out.

Is it good way to save data on lost focus of each control or any other way around?

Comment: Can you be more specific about how exactly 'that checkbox' fits into your layout? Or even give us some XAML?

Comment: There is one screen with multiple tabs and one of user control with category name and textbox beside it for which I was talking about. User will add value in that textbox for one or multiple category and just click on any other area on screen, new tab or close button.